# Rectangular boxes do not position based on cell.left and cell.top in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a default schedule on excel, which will put blocks at regular intervals.
However, no matter what I try, the further away from column 1 I go, the more further away from my intended position the boxes are.
What am I doing incorrect here?
Also, I am very new to VBA. If you have any tips to improve the code, that is also welcome :)
Following is the code:

```vb
'Home sheet B3: Start date value: 01/01/2024
'Home sheet B4: End date value: 31/12/2027
'Home sheet B5: total number of days (B4-B3): 
'Home sheet G11: Start date of the first phase of schedule: 15/01/2024
'Activesheet.row 6 is date row (Check image for ref)
'Activesheet.row 7 is the schedule row (Check image for ref)
'rg: Activesheet.range("B7")

Public Function Default_Project_Milestones_Schedule_add(rg)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim days As Integer
Dim thisday As Date
Dim shp As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape
Dim w As Double
Dim interval As Double
Const we1 = 6 'Sat
Const we2 = 7 'Sun
    

days = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B5").Value
For i = 1 To days
    thisday = DateAdd("d", (i - 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("B3").Value)
    If Weekday(thisday, vbMonday) = we1 Or Weekday(thisday, vbMonday) = we2 Then
        j = j + 1
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").Range("G11") = thisday Then
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 45)
        k = rg.Offset(0, i).Top
        With shp
            .Left = rg.Offset(0, i - j).Left
            .Top = k + shp.Height / 2.5
            .Width = Range(rg.Offset(0, i - j), rg.Offset(0, i - j + (8 * 5))).Width 'Phase A considered: 8wks
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "A"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = 1
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 18
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        End With
        Set shp2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1, 1, 1, 45)
        w = shp.Width
        interval = Range(rg.Offset(0, i - j + (8 * 5)), rg.Offset(0, i - j + (8 * 5) + (5 * 5))).Width 'Interval between phases considered: 5wks
        With shp2
            .Left = w + interval + rg.Offset(0, i - j).Left
            .Top = k + shp2.Height / 2.5
            .Width = Range(rg.Offset(0, i - j + (8 * 5) + (5 * 5)), rg.Offset(0, i - j + (8 * 5) + (5 * 5) + (6 * 5))).Width 'Phase B considered: 6wks
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "B"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = 1
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 18
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

If the phase A start date is 15Jan, 2024. Then end date should be 9Mar (8 weeks) But, there is a small extra that comes. I have no clue why.
output image

[image: 1]

I have explained everything in the box above

Comment: Please post the whole `Sub` code instead of part of it. What's the value of G11? `rg: Activecell.range("B7")` Do you mean `ActiveSheet.Range("B7")`?

Comment: The whole sub code is pretty big. 
As mentioned above, G11 is the start date of the first phase. 
Also, yes I meant Activesheet.Range. My mistake. Apologies. I’ll correct

Comment: `G11 is the start date of the first phase` Nobody can debug your code without its value. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, here you go  
Home sheet B3.value (Start date of schedule) = 01/01/2024,  
Home sheet B4.value (End date of schedule) = 31/12/2027,  
Home sheet G11.value (Start date of Phase A) = 15/01/2024,

Answer (score 0):

- The code snippet in your post is part of your project, and it's challenging to ensure that the revision won't impact the entire project.
- Here's a demonstration to add a bar chart to the project.
- The value in the 6th row should represent a date. The date format displayed in the cell doesn't matter.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim oShp As Shape, rDate As Range
    Dim sDate As Long, eDate As Long
    Dim sLoc, eLoc, iCnt As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Const WK_CNT = 8
    Const DATE_ROW = 6
    Const H_RATIO = 0.5 ' Bar height/row height
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    Call RemoveShp(oSht)
    For iCnt = 0 To 1
        ' Get the start and end date
        sDate = oSht.Cells(11 + iCnt, "G").Value ' 2024/1/15
        eDate = sDate + WK_CNT * 7 - 1
        ' Date row
        Set rDate = oSht.Rows(DATE_ROW)
        ' Locate the start and end date
        sLoc = Application.Match(sDate, rDate, 0)
        If IsError(sLoc) Then sLoc = Application.Match(sDate, rDate, 1)
        eLoc = Application.Match(eDate, rDate, 0)
        If IsError(eLoc) Then eLoc = Application.Match(eDate, rDate, 1)
        If Not (IsError(sLoc) Or IsError(eLoc)) Then
            If eLoc > sLoc Then
                ' Add Rect
                With oSht.Range(Cells(1, sLoc), Cells(1, eLoc)).Offset(DATE_ROW + iCnt)
                    Set oShp = oSht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                        .Left, .Top + .Height * (1 - H_RATIO) / 2, _
                        .Width, .Height * H_RATIO)
                    oShp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Project x" ' modify as needed
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Sub RemoveShp(ByVal oSht As Worksheet)
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In oSht.Shapes
        s.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated now and input the entire code in the comments. All the bars need to be in the same line, end to end with intervals in between

Comment: My snippet is a demonstration to add a bar chart to the project. You have to revised for your project. What's the `intervals`? What's on sheet Schedule? I would suggest that you uload a screenshot about the parameter setting ( start, end ..).

Comment: I introduced the parameter “intervals” to provide the space between the two phases. The phases are not immediate. 
“Schedule” is the output tab worksheet. The entire schedule is supposed to be made in that tab

Comment: It's challenging to discern the entire logic from your 300+ lines of code. I believe addressing the `intervals` issue is achievable once you identify which part needs modification in my demonstration.

Comment: Just to inform everyone, It ended up being a resolution issue. The rectangles align correctly on my laptop, but as soon as I drag the excel onto my connected screen and run the macro again, the rectangles dont line up.
I dont think there is any way to resolve this, other than to put up a disclaimer.
Thank you everyone for taking your time checking and providing answers.